# How long it takes to sync new users in group to inherit flow run permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, usergroups, power-automate

When a new user is added to an Active Directory group, Microsoft Flow doesn't reflect changes on run permissions on this new user. In fact, the new user doesn't appear to be in the group immediately (it takes some time to reflect changes)
My question is, how much time does it take to reflect changes and assign permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that an AD group in Azure AD or in on-premises AD?

If it is on-premises, you will need to consider the synchronization frequency.

If it is in Azure AD and things still don't work, then let the user sign off and/or restart their machine, because cookies about permissions can persist and not be updated immediately.

The "how long" aspect cannot be answered because Microsoft does not disclose the timing or schedule of the online jobs schedule.